# VirtualEnv + Apt + Python3 Issue

Tags: 14.04, apt, python3, virtualenv

## VirtualEnv + Apt + Python3 Issue

On 14.04 I've got an interesting problem trying to import a module. I have `python3` and `python3-apt` installed and I can verify this with the following:

```
    chalbersma@j2test:~$ python3
    Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
    [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import apt_pkg
    >>>
```

Which is great! This is how I developed the application I'm trying to develop. So now I go ahead and I want to create a virtual env so that I can add some modules without messing up the system as a whole.

```
    mkdir test
    virtualenv -p python3 ./test
    <stuff>
    chalbersma@j2test:~$ source ./test/bin/activate
    (test)chalbersma@j2test:~$
```

So now I'm in my test market. I expect my imports to show up in both so when I try to use apt

```
    (test)chalbersma@j2test:~$ python3
    Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
    [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import apt_pkg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
    >>>
```

I also tried to pip install it with `pip install apt` and `pip install apt_pkg` but neither of those work. This sort of functionality seems to work with other modules. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like there is `python-apt` on PyPI that you can use `pip` to install but that's for Python 2. For Python 3, your solution for using the `system-site-packages` is probably the only way to get the `apt_pkg` module.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/). You need to use the `--system-site-packages` option when creating your virtualenv if you want this to work. So in my example the correct way to do it would be

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./test
```

Thanks for helping guys!